# convert a JavaScript string variable to decimal/money

Tags: javascript, decimal, string-conversion

How can we convert a JavaScript string variable to decimal?

Is there a function such as:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById(amtid4).innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Yes -- [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById(amtid4).innerHTML);
```

---

For *formatting* numbers, use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var num = parseFloat(document.getElementById(amtid4).innerHTML).toFixed(2);
```

`num` is now a string with the number formatted with two decimal places.

Comment: Can we make that variable with 2 decimal points such as 120.50? right now I am getting 120.5 only.

Comment: To quote @PhilipWhitehouse "Please, to anyone reading this in the future, do not use float to store currency. You will loose precision and data. You should store it as a integer number of cents (or pennies etc.) and then convert prior to output.". Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: @SSHThis As far as I'm aware JavaScript doesn't have an integer type. It only has a Number type which are all stored internally as 64bit floating point numbers. Your point is valid for other languages that do have integer types such as C#, C++, but not really for JavaScript.

Comment: @SimonBrangwin His point is still valid, but the semantics can be confusing. What he really means is "only store currency as whole numbers in javascript since they'll be stored as floating point numbers".

Comment: Just a reminder: `parseFloat('22w')` is `22` and `parseFloat('w22')` is `NaN`

Comment: When I try `parseFloat("11.0")` it results in 11 instead of 11.0

Comment: @RixTheTyrunt in what way is this not what you expect?

Comment: It's just weird that JavaScript erases the `.0` part

Answer (score 76):

You can also use the `Number` constructor/function (no need for a radix and usable for both integers and floats):

```
Number('09'); /=> 9
Number('09.0987'); /=> 9.0987
```

Alternatively like Andy E said in the comments you can use `+` for conversion

```
+'09'; /=> 9
+'09.0987'; /=> 9.0987
```

Comment: This isn't supported by IE11

Answer (score 19):

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("ru", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "GBP"
});

alert( formatter.format(1234.5) ); // 1 234,5 £
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Comment: I had no idea this existed.

Comment: Best answer by far. parseFloat? Precision hell? No, thx! `Intl.NumberFormat` nails it.

Answer (score 12):

This works:

```
var num = parseFloat(document.getElementById(amtid4).innerHTML, 10).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: It works if the decimals are not zeros, for instance:
`parseFloat('32.00').toFixed(2)` returns `32`, and not 32.00

Answer (score 2):

An easy short hand way would be to use +x
It keeps the sign intact as well as the decimal numbers.
The other alternative is to use parseFloat(x).
Difference between parseFloat(x) and +x is for a blank string +x returns 0 where as parseFloat(x) returns NaN.

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly risky to rely on javascript functions to compare and play with numbers. In javascript (0.1+0.2 == 0.3) will return false due to rounding errors. Use the math.js library.

Answer (score 2):

I made a little helper function to do this and catch all malformed data

```
const convertToPounds = (str = "", asNumber = false) => {
  let num = Number.parseFloat(str);
  if (isNaN(num) || num < 0) num = 0;
  if (asNumber) return Math.round(num * 1e2) / 1e2
  return num.toFixed(2);
};
```

Demo is [here](https://codepen.io/sidonaldson/pen/NWBZNRe)

Comment: This function returns a string, not a number!

Comment: @MarioNezmah good point. Have updated to allow the option to return a number. I used toFixed because I was using it to display the converted number on a webpage so it made sense

Answer (score 0):

Prefix `+` could be used to convert a string form of a number to a number (say "009" to 9)

```
const myNum = +"009"; // 9
```

But be `careful` if you want to `SUM` 2 or more number strings into one number.

```
const myNum = "001" + "009";   // "001009"  (NOT 10)

const myNum = +"001" + +"009"; // 10
```

Alternatively you can do

```
const myNum = Number("001") + Number("009"); // 10
```