# Converting string into number

Tags: javascript, json, math

Hi can anyone let me know the logic to convert the `string` into `number` with two decimal using inbuilt JavaScript methods

The input value is a `JSON` string

Ex1: 123 just need to convert to 1.23

Ex2: 153 to 1.53

Ex3: 100 to 1.00

Comment: Like... `var output = inputValue / 100;`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095795/convert-a-javascript-string-variable-to-decimal-money

Comment: That will fail in case of 100.

Comment: 100 has to get convert into 1.00

Comment: use this  (input/100).toFixed(2)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest dividing by 100 by *also* using `toFixed(2)` to ensure that we always end up with at most two decimal places, which seems to be part of your reporting requirement.

```js
var input = 123.456;
console.log(input);
output = (input / 100).toFixed(2);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```js
console.log((Number('123') / 100).toFixed(2));
console.log((Number('100') / 100).toFixed(2));
console.log((Number('156') / 100).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: a string, divided by a number will be auto-coerced to number. So you don't need `Number()`.

Comment: Understand @31piy

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log((Number('123') / 100).toFixed(2));
console.log((Number('100') / 100).toFixed(2));
console.log((Number('156') / 100).toFixed(2));
console.log((Number('100') / 100).toFixed(2));
```

Note:- You can use the inbuilt Number() function to convert the string to a number, then divide by 100.

Comment: 100 /100 give 1 not 1.00

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt Number() function to convert the string to a number, then divide by 100:

```js
function convertNumber(input) {
    return (input) ? (Number(input) / 100).toFixed(2): null;
}

console.log("Result:", convertNumber("123"));
console.log("Result:", convertNumber("153"));
console.log("Result:", convertNumber("176"));
console.log("Result:", convertNumber("100"));
console.log("Result:", convertNumber(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parseInt() function to convert string to integer

For example:

```
var x = parseInt("100")
```